# BeautifulSoup - ошибка AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Имею такой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Данные
def parse():
    URL = "https://eda.ru/recepty"
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
    }

#Переменные и словари
    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'clearfix')
    rezs = []

#Черпаем все из блока и добавляем полученную информацию в словарь rez
    for item in items:
        rezs.append({
            'title': item.find('a', class_ = 'item-title__special item-title__special_logo').get_text(strip = True)
        })

#Проходимсь по словарю и выводим из него инфу
        for rez in rezs:
            print(rez['title'])

parse()
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' File "C:\Code\parser.py", line 20, in parse 'title': item.find('a', class_ = 'item-title__special item-title__special_logo').get_text(strip = True) File "C:\Code\parser.py", line 27, in  parse()

Comment: Вот текст ошибки: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
  File "C:\Code\parser.py", line 20, in parse
    'title': item.find('a', class_ = 'item-title__special item-title__special_logo').get_text(strip = True)
  File "C:\Code\parser.py", line 27, in <module>
    parse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.find('a', class_ = 'item-title__special item-title__special_logo')
```

Данный участок кода возвращает значение `None`, судя по всему из-за того, что `find()` ничего не находит, а вы пытаетесь применить к нему `get_text`